# Why is Outlook 2010 showing the “To Address” in the navigation pane?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

This one is difficult to explain... In the Outlook 2010 navigation pane I arrange my email by Date with the newest on the top. However each email preview,along with the subject, shows the "To" address instead of the "From" address.

This means that I have an inbox where all emails have the same address on them, my own, instead of the person who sent me the email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on one of the fields and click on FIELD CHOOSER. Then simply drag the TO field away and drag in the FROM field.

Comment: This worked, thanks!I had to open Outlook in Debug mode (by holding down Ctrl as I double clicked the icon) before I could access this menu. Maybe this wasn't necessary.

Comment: Great! No, being in Safe Mode for Outlook should not be necessary; I can change the displayed fields just fine in normal mode.